# how to simulate click on tab in jest/enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I want to write a simple test
1- Click on tab
2- see state is resurrect changed
3- tab content real is changed

My Problem is wen simulate click is fired but setState not working

```
test('selected tab change when click on tab', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />)
  const walletTab1 = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'wallet-tab-1').dive().dive().dive().dive()


  console.log('shaloww',walletTab1.debug())
  walletTab1.simulate('click')

  const walletTabContainer = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'wallet-tab-container-1')

  expect(walletTabContainer.length).toBe(1)
})
```

### MyComponent

```
        <AppBar position="static" color="default" data-test="component-wallet">
          <Tabs
            data-test="wallet-tabs"
            value={selectedTab}
            onChange={(event, value) => {
               this.setState({selectedTab: val})
            }}
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
            variant="scrollable"
            scrollButtons="auto"
          >
            <Tab data-test="wallet-tab-0" label="Item One" />
            <Tab data-test="wallet-tab-1" label="Item Two" />
            <Tab data-test="wallet-tab-2" label="Item Three" />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        {selectedTab === 0 && <TabContainer data-test="wallet-tab-container-0">Item One</TabContainer>}
        {selectedTab === 1 && <TabContainer data-test="wallet-tab-container-1">Item Two</TabContainer>}
        {selectedTab === 2 && <TabContainer data-test="wallet-tab-container-2">Item Three</TabContainer>}
```

after click should be state (selectedTab) update to 1

Comment: What do you mean by "is resurrected"?

Comment: @TalKoren Onclick is defined by tabs we are clicking on a tab
in dom with trigger button inside tab -> onClick tabs working as well 
but in enzyme onClick not happened

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={(event, value) => {
  this.setState({selectedTab: val})
}}
```

There is no such thing called `val` in your code, your function's parameter is `value`.
That is the problem I think.